# Is annihilator isomorphic to orthogonal complement in inner product space?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was trying to figure out the relationship between the notion of orthogonal complements and annihilators because many properties of them have a lot in common.
Suppose $U\le V$ and $V$ is a finite dimensional linear space, for example $\dim U^0+\dim U=\dim V$ and so is $\dim U+\dim U^\bot=\dim V$;$\{0\}^0=V^\prime$,$V^0=\{0\}$ and $\{0\}^\bot =V$,$V^\bot=\{0\}$, since $V^\prime$ and $V$ are isomorphic, the properties again match up.
So I tried to prove that orthogonal complement of $U$ are isomorphic to annihilator of $U$, as follows:
Every element $u$ in $U^\bot$ induced a linear functional $\varphi:v\mapsto \langle v,u\rangle$, which by definition lies in $U^0$, this show there exists an injection $U^\bot\hookrightarrow U^0$.Conversely by Riesz Representation Theorem, for every element $\varphi\in U^0$, there exists a unique $u\in U$ such that $\varphi=\langle \cdot,u\rangle$. By previous argument, there is a natural isomorphism between $U^0$ and $U^\bot$.
However I'm not so confident about my proof, so I was wondering whether my proof is correct and if not, please help me pin out where my proof goes wrong.
And if my proof is correct, it used the assumption that $V$ are finite dimensional. If $V$ is infinite dimensional, will the proposition still holds?

Comment: Yes, for finite dimensions, your argument is fine.